# round/circle image with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

[image]

New to Kivy. Is there a way to crop a square image to a circle one with kivy when presenting it? Thanks!

Comment: You can set the `source` of an Ellipse instruction, or use Stencil instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a canvas and set it to Elipse as follow:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Ellipse:
                pos: 280, 200
                size: 200 , 200 
                source: 'image.jpg'
                angle_start: 0
                angle_end: 360

'''
class App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

App().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDScreen:

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "data/logo/kivy-icon-512.png"
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```